# Make DIV visible on LI click

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have a `div` id "overlay" that I want to make visible when the user clicks on the `li` that encloses it.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="album" id="nirvana-nevermind">
         <div id="overlay">
              <a href="http://www.nirvana.com">Nirvana</a> Nevermind
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#overlay { visibility: hidden; }
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".album").click(function() {
    //need the following to toggle
    $("#overlay").css("visibility", "visible");    
});

$("#overlay").click(function() {
    window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});

});
```

**Update:** The code is working now. I've modified the code to what I am using. The DIV#overlay shows when the LI.album is clicked, however, I have more than one of these LI.albums next to each other and no matter which LI is clicked, the #overlay only shows on the very first LI. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please include example HTML, rather than trying to describe it... you may miss a vital detail. Suggest you put demo code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in how you've used the `css()` jQuery method. You need to use a `,` to seperate the property and the value rather than a `:`.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".album").click(function() {
    $("#overlay").css("visibility", "visible");
});

});
```

[See here for a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgZCc/) on jFiddle.

(Note that the OP changed how they'd written the property in the question since writing this.)

**UPDATE**

I've [updated the code on JSFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgZCc/2/) to show how you can do this with multiple `li`'s.

[See here for the full JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cgZCc/2/)

Firsly I've changed your id overlay to be a class instead. This is because an ID can only exist once in any given HTML document. It's a unique identifier not a container.

Thr JS Code is simply looking at the current object (the one just clicked) and finding all children with a class name of "overlay". It is then setting the visibility to visible for those items.

```
$(".album").click(function() {
   $(this).children(".overlay").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Comment: Done! Thanks. Any idea how to fix the new problem I'm having? I added it in the update to the original post

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
 $("#overlay").css("visibility":"visible");
```

use

```
 $("#overlay").show();
```

or

```
 $("#overlay").css("visibility","visible");
```

To make it disappear after some period of time, take a look at the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/window.setTimeout) method and use

```
 $("#overlay").hide();
```

Comment: Shit, I just edited the post before you commented. Any idea how to make it invisible after a while? Some kind of timeout feature

Comment: @yatman, answer updated, but your should add that to your question.

Comment: Okay, got it working! BUT the problem I'm now having is that I have several of these LIs next to each other.. and when any one of them is clicked, the overlay shows on the first LI, not the one that is clicked.

Comment: @yatman, you should update the question with new information and an indication of what you've changed in the question

Comment: Also if you're having multiple "#overlay" items, that would be invalid. You can only use an id once in any given html document. (it's a unique identifier not a container name).

Comment: `.show()` is not equivalent to `.css("visibility","visible");`. It is equivalent to `.css('display', 'block')`.

Comment: @melhosseiny: agreed, but given the OP's description, I'm guessing he should be using show and hide anyway

Comment: @Dancrumb But he wants to click on them. If you use `.hide()`, they'll be gone and there'll be nothing to click.

Comment: He wants to click on the `LI`s, not the `DIV`s. It's the `DIV`s that are going to be hidden.

Comment: @Dancrumb If you hide all the element's children (which is the case here), the element won't be clickable. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYCe8/1/) for proof.

Comment: @melhosseiny: absolutely right... thanks for sticking with that point. If an HTML element has no visible children, then there's nothing on the screen to click.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$("#overlay").css("visibility":"visible");
```

to

```
$("#overlay").css("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with doing $("#overlay").css({visibility: "visible"});

Comment: @tbleckert: you are correct, but that's not what the OP had, originally

Answer (score 1):

Change `$("#overlay").css("visibility":"visible");` to:

```
$(this).children("#overlay").css("visibility", "visible");
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNvG8/1/) for a live example.

Note: You should change `overlay` to a class attribute.

Comment: Got it, thanks! if you could look at the update I edited in the post and help me with my new problem, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: This code fixes your multiple `li` issue. I added a live example.

Comment: Wow, that worked well. I had no idea you could specify .children. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean? Do you want it too automatically hide #overlay? " How do I change my code so that it toggles off after some time?". If you want it automatically, do this:

```
var hide = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#overlay').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}, 5000);
```

And keep in mind that setting visibility to hidden only hides it but still taking up the space. Setting **display: none (hide())** hides it completely.

Another thing is that you shouldn't use an id to that div. As you probably know, a ID can only be used once, that said you can never use your function on multiple li's with the same functionality. I would make it a class and then:

```
$('.album').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.overlay').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

This way it will work on every li that has an overlay div.